# Tab commands in Adobe Brackets?

Tags: ide, text-editor, hotkeys, adobe-brackets

Sublime has the ability to enter tags when typing the unbracketed word + TAB. Is there any way to recreate this functionality in Brackets? I went through their entire extension list but didn't see anything for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What u want is "emmet" extension. It's actually in the extension list.